# Error when executing tcpdump command

Tags: tcpdump

When I enter `tcpdump` command in the terminal, I see the following error:

[image]

When executing `sudo tcpdump` I see this error:

[image]

After this I tried to execute the following command:

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

to which I get this error:

```
tcpdump:eth0:you don't have permission to capture on that device(socket:operation not permitted)
```

Kindly guide.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run tcpdump with sudo or as root, else it wont be able to acces the network interface in promiscuous mode. And if you want to monitor anything else that intheface 0, you have to use `-i` option.

So something like:

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0
```

would do it. Use

```
ifconfig
```

to see which network interfaces that are configured. And

```
iwconfig
```

to identify which one is WiFi.